# How do I GetModuleFileName() if I only have a window handle (hWnd)?

Tags: c#, winapi, hwnd, getmodulefilename

I'm trying to get the name of the executable of a window that is outside my C# 2.0 application. My app currently gets a window handle (hWnd) using the GetForegroundWindow() call from "user32.dll".

From the digging that I've been able to do, I think I want to use the GetModuleFileNameEx() function (from PSAPI) to obtain the name, but GetModuleFileNameEx() requires a handle to a Process, not a Window.

Is it possible to get a process handle from a window handle? (Do I need to get the thread handle of the window first?)

EDITED the first sentence to make it clearer what I'm trying to do.

**UPDATE!** Here's the C# code that I found worked for me. The only caveat is *occasionally* it returns a file/path where the drive letter is a "?" instead of the actual drive letter (like "C"). -- Haven't figured out why yet.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, Int32 bInheritHandle, UInt32 dwProcessId);

[DllImport("psapi.dll")]
static extern uint GetModuleFileNameEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr hModule, [Out] StringBuilder lpBaseName, [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int nSize);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

private string GetWindowModuleFileName(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    uint processId = 0;
    const int nChars = 1024;
    StringBuilder filename = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processId);
    IntPtr hProcess = OpenProcess(1040, 0, processId);
    GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess,IntPtr.Zero,filename,nChars);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return (filename.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Works okay for me.  Needs if ((int)hProcess != 0) after OpenProcess()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx) and that will return you the process associated with the window.

From that, you can call [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320.aspx) to open the process and get the handle to the process.

Comment: Hey welcome to stack overflow - I've been a long time reader of yours

Answer (score 8):

Been struggling with the same problem for an hour now, also got the first letter replaced by a **?** by using GetModuleFileNameEx.
Finaly came up with this solution using the **System.Diagnostics.Process** class.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

void GetProcessPathFromWindowHandle(IntPtr hwnd)
{
   uint pid = 0;
   Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
   Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
   return p.MainModule.FileName;
}
```

Comment: I think this is, by far, the best solution offered here. No strange characters and, most importantly, not relying on the inconsistent GetModuleFileNameEx function, which on Windows 7 is located in another DLL (not psapi but kernel32). Using a .Net class is definitely preferred in this case. Works perfectly.

Comment: I realize this thread is outdated, but a small remark on this suggested solution. This won't work if you try to obtain the filename of a 64bits process from a 32bits process (or vice versa).

Comment: Not applicable for Microsoft Store apps on Windows 10, calls on different app windows constantly return "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\ApplicationFrameHost.exe".

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on a windows 64 bit platform, you may need to use QueryFullProcessImageName instead.  This returns a user style path, compared to GetProcessImageFileName which returns a system style path that would need to be converted using NtQuerySymbolicLinkObject or ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject.

One mammoth example function - recommend breaking up into re usable bits.

```
typedef DWORD (__stdcall *PfnQueryFullProcessImageName)(HANDLE hProcess, DWORD dwFlags, LPTSTR lpImageFileName, PDWORD nSize);
typedef DWORD (__stdcall *PfnGetModuleFileNameEx)(HANDLE hProcess, HMODULE hModule, LPTSTR lpImageFileName, DWORD nSize);

std::wstring GetExeName( HWND hWnd ){
// Convert from Window to Process ID
DWORD dwProcessID = 0;
::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwProcessID);

// Get a handle to the process from the Process ID
HANDLE hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwProcessID);

// Get the process name
if (NULL != hProcess) {
    TCHAR szEXEName[MAX_PATH*2] = {L'\0'};
    DWORD nExeName = sizeof(szEXEName)/sizeof(TCHAR);

    //  the QueryFullProcessImageNameW does not exist on W2K
    HINSTANCE hKernal32dll = LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");
    PfnQueryFullProcessImageName pfnQueryFullProcessImageName = NULL;
    if(hKernal32dll != NULL) {
        pfnQueryFullProcessImageName = (PfnQueryFullProcessImageName)GetProcAddress(hKernal32dll, "QueryFullProcessImageNameW");
        if (pfnQueryFullProcessImageName != NULL) 
            pfnQueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, szEXEName, &nExeName);
        ::FreeLibrary(hKernal32dll);
    } 

    // The following was not working from 32 querying of 64 bit processes
    // Use as backup for when function above is not available 
    if( pfnQueryFullProcessImageName == NULL ){ 
        HINSTANCE hPsapidll = LoadLibrary(L"Psapi.dll");
        PfnGetModuleFileNameEx pfnGetModuleFileNameEx = (PfnGetModuleFileNameEx)GetProcAddress(hPsapidll, "GetModuleFileNameExW");
        if( pfnGetModuleFileNameEx != NULL )    
            pfnGetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, szEXEName, sizeof(szEXEName)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        ::FreeLibrary(hPsapidll);
    }

    ::CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return( szEXEName );
} 
return std::wstring();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is it that you're trying to do?  You can get the process ID of the the process which created a window with [GetWindowThreadProcessId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(VS.85).aspx), followed by [OpenProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(VS.85).aspx) to get the process handle.  But this seems very kludgy, and I feel like there's a more elegant way to do what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe it seems kludgy to you, but someone with reputation of 1 gave the exact same answer just 1 minute before you, and I don't think his reputation is going to stay at 1 for very long.

Comment: Yes, it feels kludgy to me, too. I'm trying to track which window has focus. Naturally, window handles and title bar names change, but the application exe name doesn't.

Comment: OK, but anyway Larry Osterman gave the same answer so it's probably less klugy than all of the alternatives.  And his reputation isn't 1 any more.

Comment: Larry Osterman's lifetime reputation in windows programming is right up there with Raymond Chen's

Comment: Larry Osterman's answer has just been accepted so now his reputation is 46.  His lifetime prior to SO doesn't count.

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the file name of the executable :

C#:

```
string file = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
```

mfg

Comment: This is a bit of an old question now, but at the time, I was trying to get the EXE name of *another* process based on process ID. (Not the one that was running.) So this isn't helpful answer in this context.