# How to detect is a process has any VISIBLE windows (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, process, window

I a want to be able to detect if a process  has any windows that are visible to user, I don't really mind false positives (saying that a process is invisible when it is actually visible) but the opposite is a problem (Saying that a process is invisible when it really isn't). For this reason the `CInt(Process.MainWindowHandle) = 0` and `Process.MainWindowTitle = ""` don't do what I need.

Comment: Please find some useful information here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635404/how-to-get-process-name-and-title-of-the-top-window-on-windows-c-sharp

Comment: This approach has the same problem as `CInt(Process.MainWindowHandle) = 0` Thanks though

Comment: `Process.MainWindowHandle = 0` should take care of most of the cases. Also you might include `Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow` to make completely sure. Can you please post your exact conditions (and code) to help us understand better what might be the problem? On the other hand, bear in mind that there are cases where various windows are associated with the same process; in these cases, it might become a bit tricky.

Comment: What I want is some way of getting a .HasAnyVisibleWindows (psuedocode) property of a process object. I don't have any exact conditions as I have a feeling that this may not be possible perfectly due to special cases like you mentioned. So only the conditions in the original question really apply.  Please bear in mind that the process object was not started by me it was one process from the `Process.GetProcesses` method.

Comment: As said Process.MainWindowHandle = 0 should take care of most of the cases (no matter if you started the process or not); and together with Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow (which is a boolean flag present in all the running processes, not necessarily started by you) should take care of most of the situations. At least regarding processes; if you want to account for multiple-windows per process, you would have to rely on an API-based approach (as the one suggested in the answer you got; never tried it, but might be worth trying). PS: if you don't write @my-nick I might not get your replies.

Comment: PPS: although logically the problem in these last cases will be getting the handles for the given windows, what might require further API calls or even a proper understand of how works the given program (-> horrible news because would imply a serious restriction to your intention of creating a generally-applicable approach). Ideally, you should locate a situation not accounted properly by the "standard methods" (i.e., MainWindowHandle = 0) and write it here as an example to help the helpers to propose accurate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I google'd and found this Function: [IsWindowVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Have you tried it?

Comment: This looks like it could be used in conjunction with the properties in the original question, to improve it. I will get the window handle from the process object and test the visibility and existence of the window. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to load a process so try using it this way.

```
do
process.refresh()
Process.MainWindowTitle.tostring.length >0
loop

msgbox(process.mainwindowtitle.tostring)
```

This should work