# How do I filter the list of windows to find just the 'real' ones in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, winapi, window, .net-5

I'd like to write a program that saves the position of my open windows, and restores them, so I can move between different multi-monitor setups at work and home.

There are some excellent old questions for listing all the windows, such as:

[How do I find all windows using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717667/how-do-i-find-all-windows-using-c)

[How to get and set the window position of another application in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364440/how-to-get-and-set-the-window-position-of-another-application-in-c-sharp)

[How to get process name and title of the top window on Windows / C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635404/how-to-get-process-name-and-title-of-the-top-window-on-windows-c-sharp)

The problem is that while I have 10-15 windows open (and visible on the task bar), all these solutions return *thousands* of windows. These solutions probably worked nicely 10 years ago, but are unmanageable in Windows10.

It appears that not only is every browser tab a window, but so is every item on the task bar, as are icons in the notification area. In some cases individual controls appear in the list, and there are loads of others that I can't identify.

jiverson's excellent WindowList class (from the first of those questions) gives me a tree with 'only' 500+ windows. I can trim the list down a bit by ignoring windows with a size of zero, but it still leaves lots of things that can't be moved around by the user.

Is there any way to filter this list to 'real' windows that live on the desktop?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "real". Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210504/enumerate-windows-like-alt-tab-does and this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606

Comment: What makes you think these windows aren't real? If you want to filter out onoes that are transparent, have no size, or are invisible, that is a different question

Comment: @SimonMourier - thanks, that looks very promising. 'appearing on the alt+tab list' seems like a good definition of a 'real' window.

Comment: @RobinBennett see [Which windows appear in the Alt+Tab list?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863) and [c# – Enumerate windows like alt-tab does](https://techhelpnotes.com/c-enumerate-windows-like-alt-tab-does/)