# How to Get Active Process Name in C#?

Tags: c#

How to get active process name in C#?

I know that I must use this code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

but I don't know how use it.

Comment: You should be aware that trying to use `GetForegroundWindow` along with any other functions (e.g. `GetProcessesByName`, as shown by Gustavo's answer) is subject to race conditions. The system can change between obtaining the return values from each function (doesn't matter which order they're called in), such that you won't be able to guarantee finding corresponding values from the two. Perhaps if you explain what you intend to do with this value, a better response might be obtained.

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277085/how-do-i-getmodulefilename-if-i-only-have-a-window-handle-hwnd/321343#321343), you have to use `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the process id for the window and then you can use the `Process`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

string GetActiveProcessFileName()
{
    IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    uint pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
    p.MainModule.FileName.Dump();
}
```

Be aware that this seems to throw an exception (“A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process”) when run from a 32-bit application when the active process is 64-bit.

**EDIT:** As Damien pointed out, this code is prone to race conditions, because the process that had the active window at the time when `GetForegroundWindow()` was called might not exist anymore when `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` is called. Even worse situation would be if the same hwnd would be assigned to another window at that time, but I guess this should be really rare.

Comment: with this API and this function your assembly will be TR/Dropper.MSIL.Gen by some AV

Comment: I haven't tested it, but [`GetProcessImageFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683217.aspx) might avoid the 64 bit problem.

Comment: using ``p.processName`` insted of  ``p.MainModule.FileName``  avoids  32-64bit cant access error

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest using `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

```
var currentProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
string name = currentProc.ProcessName;
```

As an alternative you could use:

```
string name = currentProc.MainModule.FileName;
```

Comment: Because he mentions `GetForegroundWindow()`, I think he wants the process of the currently active window, not the current process.

Answer (score 3):

Its just need two line of code, you can use linq to get all processes.

```
var processss = from proc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses() orderby proc.ProcessName ascending select proc;
foreach (var item in processss) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ProcessName );
}
```

Now you have all active process by just on line.

Comment: Note that the question asks for the name of the currently active process.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link describing the exact thing you want to do:

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/GetActiveProcess.aspx

And another one describing the [`GetForegroundWindow`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetForegroundWindow.html) function, which I copy below.

Note that you may need to reference some extra assemblies, for this code to work. 
Look at the MSDN for each function. Example, [`GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) requires System.Diagnostics.

```
public ApplicationState AppState
{
    get
    {
        Process[] processCollection =
                           Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName);
        if(processCollection != null && 
           processCollection.Length  >= 1 && 
            processCollection[0] != null)
        {
            IntPtr activeWindowHandle = Win32.GetForegroundWindow();
            // Optional int ProcessID;
            // Optional Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(
                                                 GetForegroundWindow(), 
                                                 out ProcessID)
            foreach(Process wordProcess in processCollection)
            {
                //Optional if( ProcessID == wordProcess.Id )
                //          return ApplicationState.Focused;
                if(wordProcess.MainWindowHandle == activeWindowHandle)
                {
                    return ApplicationState.Focused;
                }
            }

            return ApplicationState.Running;
        }

        return ApplicationState.NotRunning;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void GetProcessNames()
    {
        List<string> windowNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (Process window in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (window.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {                    
                windowNames.Add(window.MainWindowTitle);
            }

            // It's that simple
        }
    }
```