# How to make a countdown timer that only begins in certain programs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, timer, countdowntimer

So before I begin, I would like you to know I already know how to make the timer. My only problem is making it only work when I am using certain programs. I am knew to programming and I want the timer to count back from 10,000 (you know, to do the ten thousand hour rule, yes I have already done a couple hundred but I would like to keep track of my progress). I want the timer to run on my desktop whenever I open my visual studio but I have no idea how to make this happen and I have had no luck on google with this so far, so any suggestions would really help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I want the timer to run on my desktop` ? pls make it clear

Comment: To elaborate, I meant in the background, so that I wouldn't have to minimise it every time I open up vs, but I would still like to be able to maximise it so I can see the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName");//Add visuals procname here
            if (proc.Length > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process running");
                if (timer1.Enabled == false)
                {
                    timer1.Start();//Starts the countdown}
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Process not running");
                    if (timer1.Enabled == true)
                    {
                        timer1.Stop();//Stops the countdown}
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your counter app you could set up a "process watcher" that checks this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] procList = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process p in procList ){
    if(p.ProcessName == "<visual studio process name>")
    { /*start the timer*/}
}
```

every minute, say. If it finds visual studio, then have it start your timer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just track if the process is opened as explained in this answer :[How to Get Active Process Name in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569405/how-to-get-active-process-name-in-c)