# C# RegisterHotKey - Want to know which process invoked it

Tags: c#, registerhotkey

My RegisterHotKey is working perfect:

```
bool Bnk = Form1.RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, this.GetType().GetHashCode(), 0x0000, 0xC0);  
....  
[DllImport("user32.dll")]  
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id,    int fsModifiers, int vlc);  
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)  
.....
```

From any application when Grave(`), is pressed the Hot key gets called.

Now, I want to know which application has invoked Grave(`) e.g. WINWORD / NOTEPAD / EXEL etc.

```
string CallingProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(CallingProcess);
```

always returns 'MyHotKey', the name of my c# program.

Comment: See [How to Get Active Process Name in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569405/how-to-get-active-process-name-in-c)

Comment: ` Process.GetCurrentProcess()` doesn't return calling process. It returns the current process which is your running process.

Comment: `this.GetType().GetHashCode()` <- WTF

Comment: If you need to know then you're doing it wrong and almost certainly require SetWindowsHookEx() instead.