# Hook to select Process

Tags: c#, mousekeyhook

how to use this lib to hook key and mouse to target process not global not my app

```
public void Subscribe()
{
    // Note: for the application hook, use the Hook.AppEvents() instead
    m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();

    m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt += GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
    m_GlobalHook.KeyPress += GlobalHookKeyPress;
}
```

// Note: for the application hook, use the Hook.AppEvents() instead

but how to get the target app or process ?

Comment: The library you use does not give you the option to hook a specific process.  So you have to do it the other way around, in your event handler find out which process is in the foreground.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569405/how-to-get-active-process-name-in-c

Comment: Thanx for replay. I did it with this way but i hoped there is away to target selected process