# (Converting c# to Java JNA) - GetModuleFileName from hwnd

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to do exactly what is being done over here: [How do I GetModuleFileName() if I only have a window handle (hWnd)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277085/how-do-i-getmodulefilename-if-i-only-have-a-window-handle-hwnd)

But in java instead of C#.

So far I have managed to this:

```
public static final int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;

public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
    int GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND hwnd, IntByReference pid);
};

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32)Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
    public Pointer OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, boolean bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
    public int GetTickCount();
};

public interface psapi extends StdCallLibrary {
    psapi INSTANCE = (psapi)Native.loadLibrary("psapi", psapi.class);
    int GetModuleFileNameExA (Pointer process, Pointer hModule, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

};


public static String getModuleFilename(HWND hwnd)
{

    byte[] exePathname = new byte[512];

    Pointer zero = new Pointer(0);
    IntByReference pid = new IntByReference();
    User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pid);
    System.out.println("PID is " + pid.getValue());

    Pointer process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, pid.getValue());
    int result = psapi.INSTANCE.GetModuleFileNameExA(process, zero, exePathname, 512);
    String text = Native.toString(exePathname).substring(0, result);
    return text;



}
```

The window handle that is given is valid, and the PID is always printed successfully. "`Process`" appears to return a value but the "`result`" is always zero. Could anyone knowledgeable about JNA kindly show me where my mistake is?

**EDIT: Finally, SUCCESS!** The problem was this line (where the first value had to be `1040`):

```
Pointer process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(1040, false, pid.getValue());
```

Comment: Interesting.  I assume you mean `0x1040`?  According to MSDN, this is the union of `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` and `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE`.  What happens if you just use `0x1000` (removing the `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE`)?  I am guessing it was switching to `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` that made the difference.

Comment: P.S.  This is based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880(v=VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the reason it's failing, but I think the `dwProcessId` parameter should be an `int`, not `IntByReference`.

See MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320(v=VS.85).aspx):

```
HANDLE WINAPI OpenProcess(
  __in  DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
  __in  BOOL bInheritHandle,
  __in  DWORD dwProcessId
);
```

It's just a regular DWORD.

Also, you can use [GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to return more information about why the function call failed.  Finally, this is a long shot, but your declaration of `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` is not included in the code snippet -- make sure it has the correct value (0x0400).

Comment: Thanks! I got one step closer to the solution. Process is now not giving me null. GetModuleFileNameExA is still failing though.

Comment: Interesting. GetLastError() returns access is denied. Not after OpenProcess, but after GetModuleFileNameExA

Answer (score 1):

why all the hassle with the process id ??

quoting from the documention of [`GetModuleFilename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> hModule [in, optional]:
>
> A handle to the loaded module whose path is being requested. If
>   this parameter is NULL, GetModuleFileName retrieves the path of the
>   executable file of the current process.

if you want the module fileName of the current process, just pass `NULL` as the process id.

if you want the module filename of another process, you need specific access rights before calling `OpenProcess()`. changing the access rights is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717797%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and is quite difficult to achieve (it requires a great amount of steps to lookup the privilege name, get the luid of the privilege, adjust the privileges of the token, etc.)

Comment: I have already found a solution by setting 1040 as the first parameter of OpenProcess(). Thanks for your help though :)